# Css Animation not working in Google Chrome

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-animations

I am trying to use [this](http://codepen.io/domeri/pen/ExjvK) loader in my web site, scc animation works well in Firefox & IE but doesn't work in Google Chrome.

```
#loader{
    width: 820px;
    height: 670px;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 70px;
    background: #0d8aa5;
    position: relative;
}

#innerloader{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -60px 0 0 -60px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 10px solid #19bee1;
}


#innerloader:after {
  content: '';
  background: trasparent;
  width: 140%;
  height: 140%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100%;
  top: -20%;
  left: -20%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) -4px -5px 3px -3px;

  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
     -moz-animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
      -ms-animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
       -o-animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
          animation: rotate 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
         -o-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
            transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
         -o-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
            transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="loader"><div id="innerloader"></div></div>
```

P.S. [Here](http://codepen.io/domeri/pen/ExjvK) it's working correctly also in google chrome....

Comment: Notice that codepen provides [prefix free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the prefixed keyframe rule for WebKit browsers as well.

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
}
```